# ASP .NET Master Page and Child Page with Bootstrap, not utilising entire browser space

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Can somebody tell me why my site is not using the space on the right and left of my browser. I am using .NET framework 4.6.1 and Bootstrap 4.

Following are my pages after removing all the controls, when i keep all the controls in the page and test it, initially it leaves spaces on the right and left, but after page postback the site is rendering in full browser space. Not sure what the issue is.

My master and child pages are as follows.

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HomePage.master.cs" Inherits="HomePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Site Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .btn-group-justified {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: separate;
        }

            .btn-group-justified .btn,
            .btn-group-justified .btn-group {
                float: none;
                display: table-cell;
                width: 1%;
            }

                .btn-group-justified .btn .btn,
                .btn-group-justified .btn-group .btn {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .btn-group-justified .btn .dropdown-menu,
                .btn-group-justified .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
                    left: auto;
                }
    </style>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form id="MainForm" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdPanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="ParentDiv" class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageContent" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Child Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="HRMCareerEAF.aspx.cs" Inherits="HRMCareerEAF" MasterPageFile="~/HomePage.master"
    Title="Employment Application Form" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" EnableEventValidation="false" Theme="Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="MyHeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table  table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnPersonal" runat="server" Text="Personal" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnEducation" runat="server" Text="Education" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnExperience" runat="server" Text="Experience"  />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnExpDetails" runat="server" Text="Exp. Details"  />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSkills" runat="server" Text="Skills/Salary" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAddress" runat="server" Text="Address"  />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnFamily" runat="server" Text="Family/Health" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnGeneral" runat="server" Text="General" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnOthers" runat="server" Text="Others" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDeclarations" runat="server" Text="Declaration" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEAF" runat="server" >EAF</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogout" runat="server" >Logout</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="EAFContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:MultiView ID="MV1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="PersonalView" runat="server">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-inline col-md-6">
                            Test
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                             Test
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                             Test
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                             Test
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</asp:Content>
```

Screenshot of my page in browser is as follows.

[ScreenShot of my Page in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDP86.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply replaced

```
<div id="ParentDiv" class="container">
```

with

```
<div id="ParentDiv" class="container-fluid">
```

It worked like a magic. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Check Your .js Files Has The Left,Right,Bottom,Top Alignments**

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .btn-group-justified {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: separate;
    }

        .btn-group-justified .btn,
        .btn-group-justified .btn-group {
            float: none;
            display: table-cell;
            width: 1%;
        }

            .btn-group-justified .btn .btn,
            .btn-group-justified .btn-group .btn {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .btn-group-justified .btn .dropdown-menu,
            .btn-group-justified .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
                 left:100px ;
            }
</style>
```

**2.Js File is Change Your Alignments**

**3.On Every Js File It Has .dropdown and other controls You Have To notify and Change that ...Try to Change Your Menu and Check  (.menu)  option on Every Js Files**

**4.If You Doesn't  know That Send The all Js Files To me Or Post It..**